# How to hold data of fragments while navigating to other screens

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 viewpagers containing different fragments now I have to move to the fragment of one viewpager to fragment of another viewpager. But when I hit back the previous fragments data have to hold. The problem here is I need infinite loop navigation i.e., from fragment1 of Viewpager1 contains a textview when I click on that it has to go to details screen which is in fragment1 of viewpager2  and another textview which is in fragment1 of viewpager2 it has to go to fragment1 of viewpager1.

I have tried using stack and I can navigate but when I go to 3 or 4 levels and hit back I have lost the previous data so getting nullpointer exception.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The way I accomplish similar setup is to use an array list to hold the data and pass it around from fragment to fragment using Intent.

Alternatively create a class on the host Activity with public access method so it can be get and set from the Fragment or better still implement a callback that updates the class on the Activity from the Fragment.

This way you can have a text view for firstname input in one fragment and each time and when a text is inputed in that text view you will update the Class.Firstname property in the Activity and the when you go to the details Fragment you can get the Class.Firstname and display it.

Thanks